# Can I write a template for creating a new user?

Tags: useradd

The command `useradd  new` will create  the /home/new directory.

Is there a way to create the /home/new and /home/new/check directories when `useradd  new` is executed?

I don't want to write two commands for the job every time I create a new user.

```
useradd new
mkdir /home/new/check
```

Comment: In additon to the answer below about putting files/directories in `/etc/skel` consider using `adduser` instead of `useradd` - unless you are creating accounts with a script...

Answer (score 10):

The template used when creating a new home directory is in `/etc/skel`. Simply create the directory there and all new users will have it.